# How to find duplicate data between two tables and delete on one

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

**TABLE 1**
[image]

**TABLE 2**
[image]

As you can see, the confirmation number (121449) is the same on both tables and have the same 3/4 dates too.

I would like to delete that 3 rows of table 1 because they are on table 2.

Comment: Please provide table create code and insert queries for sample data.

Comment: @JitendraYadav should i export my tables and post it?

Comment: First get create code and yes export(only limited data) and post.

Comment: check below answer works for you or not? First use select statement to verify that appropriate records will be delete and then use delete statement.

Comment: @JitendraYadav That's exactly what i wanted, thanks my friend.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join for this.

```
DELETE T1             -- Make sure only include T1 here.
FROM tb_allinc_sin_trace T1
INNER JOIN tb_outdoors T2 ON T1.confirmation_number = T2. confirmacion_nro 
WHERE T1.dates = T2.servicio_fecha;
```

To verify which records will be deleted, you can use select statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_allinc_sin_trace T1
INNER JOIN tb_outdoors T2 ON T1.confirmation_number = T2. confirmacion_nro 
WHERE T1.dates = T2.servicio_fecha;
```

Reference:

- [MySQL Delete Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)
- [MySQL Delete Using Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/)