# DB times out or takes a long time to execute

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with one very specific procedure I am working on, either it takes roughly about 45 seconds to run and or it takes over minutes to complete. I know what the issue is, but at this time I am not sure how to get around it to be honest. In the SP, you will see a section (`while block`) commented out that basically create's a token to be inserted into the table, currently I am inserting just `TEST` to get around the blocking issue.

Here's the current working version that runs fine by just inserting a dummy value.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE userexist INT(1);
    DECLARE tokenID VARCHAR(12) default '';
    DECLARE rnd_str text;
    DECLARE ready int default 0;
    DECLARE userID INT(20) default 0;
    DECLARE lastID int default 0;

    SELECT
        su.User_ID,
        1 AS user_exist
    INTO userID, userexist
    FROM System_User su
    WHERE AES_DECRYPT(su.User_Email, 'AAAA') = email
            AND AES_DECRYPT(su.User_Password, 'AAAA') = userpassword
            AND su.User_Is_Active = 1; 

    IF userexist = 1 THEN

        UPDATE System_User_Login
            SET System_User_Login.System_Logout_Time = NOW(),
                System_User_Login.System_Logout_Type = 1        
        WHERE System_User_Login.System_Login_User_ID = userID;

        SET tokenID = 'TEST'; -- dummy value for now

        INSERT INTO System_User_Login(System_Login_Time, System_Login_Token, System_Login_User_ID, System_Token_Valid_Period)
        VALUES(NOW(), tokenID, userID, (NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY));

        SET lastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

            -- WHILE ready = 0 DO
            -- SET rnd_str = lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,16)), 12, 36), 12, 0);
            -- IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM System_User_Login sul WHERE sul.System_Login_Token = rnd_str) THEN
                -- update System_User_Login
                -- SET System_Login_Token = rnd_str
                -- WHERE System_Login_ID = lastID;

                -- SET ready = 1;
            -- END IF;
        -- END WHILE;

        SELECT 
            sul.System_Login_Token AS Token
        FROM System_User_Login sul
        WHERE sul.System_Login_ID = lastID;

    ELSE
        SELECT '0' AS Token;
    END IF;

END
```

The while loop inside this procedure is to create a new token to be assigned; I've tried before and after the insert to no avail; even triggers. I must not be seeing something and or need to rethink my approach.

Comment: You should change your way to create a unique token. Just use `timestamp` plus `some random string` to make it unique. You can add `PKID` in between to make sure it is unique. If you're using MySQL 8 have a look at `UUID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user list is high then the probability of this collision will increase. This will cause multiple iterations. You can avoid that by following

1: You can use **Universal unique identifier**s if working on **MySQL 8** but make sure length constraints matches as per your requirement.

- [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)
- [UUID Short](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short)

2: Try the following

`Unique Identifier = CONCAT(<some_random_string>, unix_timestamp, <primary_key_id>)`
So if you are setting token for `user = 4` then

```
SELECT LPAD(CONCAT(CONV(FLOOR(RAND()* POW(36,16)), 12, 36), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '4'), 25, 0);
```

- If you are not generating more than one token in one sec then `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` will make it unique.
- Further, if we are generating more than one token per sec then we reduce collision by generating a random number using `CONV(FLOOR(RAND()* POW(36,16)), 12, 36)`
- If by chance, it generates the same random string for multiple, we have a unique id for each user, which will definitely make it unique.

**Assumption**: You are not creating multiple tokens for the same user in one second if so there might be chances of getting a collision.

**Note**: If you use the second approach, you can use two SQL statements for your complete procedure. Here is [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701634/how-to-find-duplicate-data-between-two-tables-and-delete-on-one/57701742#57701742)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approach, UUID works just fine; it doesn't matter how I create a token, just needed something that was unique.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, if it works for you, do up vote. Happy to help :)